# Placing shape into MapView in Android

Tags: android, maps, overlay, android-mapview

Is there a way to place a shape (drawable or shape of any kind) that occupies a specific area in MapView (lat/lon area) not pixel area .  I need that for GeoPoint Clustering purposes

If that is not possible any guidance to do it with projection coordinates would be greatly appreciated. But using the MapView canvas to do this doesn't seem performance-wise since i recycle my Overlay Items all the time and i wish i could take advantage of that too.

Comment: Start with Overlay help to draw shape [Here you go](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2013/01/android-map-drawing-path-using-overlay.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution is to draw to the ItemizedOverlay that holds the items.

```
@Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

        // cycle through all overlays
        for (int index = 0; index < mOverlays.size(); index++) {
            OverlayItemExtended item = mOverlays.get(index);

            // Converts lat/lng-Point to coordinates on the screen
            GeoPoint point = item.getPoint();
            Point ptScreenCoord = new Point();
            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(point, ptScreenCoord);



                Paint boxPaint = new Paint();
                boxPaint.setColor(android.graphics.Color.WHITE);
                boxPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                boxPaint.setAlpha(140);
                canvas.drawCircle(ptScreenCoord.X, ptScreenCoord.y,
                        20, boxPaint);


        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at[ItemizedOverlay](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/ItemizedOverlay.html)

I'm culling from my code, so this probably wont' compile out of the box, but should give you enough to figure it out from here...

extended class:

```
    public class MyOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>
    {
    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    private Context mContext;
    private OverlayItem item;

    public MyOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) 
    {
          super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
          mContext = context;
    }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) 
    {
        mOverlays.add(overlay);

    }

    public void doPopulate()
    {
         populate();
    }




    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) 
    { 
      return mOverlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() 
    {
      return mOverlays.size();
    }
}
```

and then in your activity....

```
public void addLocations(GeoPoint _center)
{  
    final GeoPoint center = _center;

    mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();

    Drawable drawable = MyActivity.this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.map_annotation_pin);

    itemizedoverlay = new ScoopOverlay(drawable,mContext);

//add as many points as you wish...
itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(
                    new OverlayItem(new GeoPoint(/*lon lat data here*/));
                );



showResults.sendEmptyMessage(0);
}

private Handler showResults = new Handler() 
{ 
    @Override 
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
    { 
        itemizedoverlay.doPopulate();
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);

        mapView.invalidate();
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes that's true but what if i want a particular drawable to take place at all eg. Europe and another one just a town. Can't have that many drawables to choose from. I think i figured it out by drawing at the ItemizedOverlay.( With that i can have control over the  size of the drawable runtime.)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but you can see where I set the drawable, you can set whatever drawable you wish... maybe I'm not understanding the question.  Depending on which zoom level you're in, you can set a different image.  I'm not sure how to control how much space it takes up on the  map, if that's what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ty for your post. Not helpful to me but i wish it will be for others. I found the solution i'll post the code later. Overriding the draw() function of the OverLay items is the solution